# Quarkus @ConfigProperty not working with operator-sdk

Tags: java, configuration, quarkus, smallrye, operator-sdk

I have a quarkus application which skeleton was generated using [Operator-SDK](https://sdk.operatorframework.io) with the following commands:

```
> operator-sdk init --domain de.ilem0n --plugins quarkus.javaoperatorsdk.io/v1-alpha
> operator-sdk create api --version=v1alpha1 --kind=FlinkSession
```

The resulting project can be found here: [FlinkOperator](https://gitlab.com/iLem0n/flink-operator-next)

The Problem is that the quarkus configuration via @ConfigProperty only works on the generated @Controller-classes.

If i add a service (in the example `FlinkSessionReconciler.java`) the @ConfigProperties are always empty.

Whats the correct approach to enable this for all classes?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out the issue by myself.

Adding a [bean defining annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations) and injecting the service into the controller helps ;)

Comment: Thanks Peter. If this solves your problem, could you please mark this as the answer? Also feel free to file an issue if theres something that can be improved https://github.com/java-operator-sdk/java-operator-sdk/issues

Comment: @asmacdo: Thanks, I will do so when i have the necessary knowledge ;)